# How can I keep the "restore defaults" and "apply" button on an Eclipse RCP PreferencePage at the bottom?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I've made a custom PreferencePage which automatically creates the "Restore Defaults" and "Apply" buttons, however, they don't stay docked in the bottom right corner just above the "OK" and "Cancel" buttons like they do in the Eclipse IDE preferences. They just dock immediately after the last widget that I create.
[image: This is where the buttons appear for me]

How can I get those buttons to stay docked in the bottom right?

Here is the code that I have:

public class MVPrefPage extends PreferencePage implements IWorkbenchPreferencePage {

```
List<FieldEditor> editors = new ArrayList<>();

public MVPrefPage() {
}

public MVPrefPage(String title) {
    super(title);
}

public MVPrefPage(String title, ImageDescriptor image) {
    super(title, image);
}

@Override
public void init(IWorkbench workbench) {
    setPreferenceStore(MatrixVisualizationActivator.getDefault().getPreferenceStore());
}

@Override
protected Control createContents(Composite parent) {

    editors.add(new BooleanFieldEditor(MatrixSettings.TITLE_ON_PROPERTY, "Show title", parent));
    editors.add(new BooleanFieldEditor(MatrixSettings.SHOW_ROW_HEADERS_PROPERTY, "Show row headers", parent));
    editors.add(new BooleanFieldEditor(MatrixSettings.SHOW_COLUMN_HEADERS_PROPERTY, "Show column headers", parent));
    editors.add(new BooleanFieldEditor(MatrixSettings.SHOW_HIDDEN_VALUES_PROPERTY, "Show hidden values", parent));
    editors.add(new BooleanFieldEditor(MatrixSettings.SHOW_MATRIX_ELEMENT_DISPLAY_NAMES_PROPERTY,
            "Show matrix element display names", parent));
    editors.add(new BooleanFieldEditor(MatrixSettings.CHART_SYNC_HIGHLIGHTER_PROPERTY,
            "Highlight view with chart sync", parent));
    editors.add(new BooleanFieldEditor(MatrixSettings.CHART_SYNC_SCROLL_PROPERTY, "Scroll view with chart sync",
            parent));
    editors.add(new BooleanFieldEditor(MatrixSettings.VIEW_SCROLLBAR_SYNC_PROPERTY, "Add scrollbar to synchronizer",
            parent));

    String[][] entryNamesAndValues = { { "Left", "LEFT" }, { "Right", "RIGHT" }, { "Center", "CENTER" } };
    editors.add(new ComboFieldEditor(MatrixSettings.VIEW_SNAP_PROPERTY, "Grid snap setting", entryNamesAndValues,
            parent));

    editors.stream().forEach(fe -> {
        fe.setPreferenceStore(getPreferenceStore());
        fe.fillIntoGrid(parent, 2);
        fe.load();
    });

    return parent;
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferencePage#performDefaults()
 */
@Override
protected void performDefaults() {
    editors.stream().forEach(fe -> fe.loadDefault());
    super.performDefaults();
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferencePage#performOk()
 */
@Override
public boolean performOk() {
    editors.stream().forEach(fe -> fe.store());
    return super.performOk();
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferencePage#performApply()
 */
@Override
protected void performApply() {
    super.performApply();
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.DialogPage#dispose()
 */
@Override
public void dispose() {
    editors.stream().forEach(fe -> fe.dispose());
    super.dispose();
}
```

Comment: This should just work. You are probably doing something wrong in your preference page. Show us a [mcve] demonstrating the problem. Particularly what you do in the `createContents` method.

Comment: I have edited the post to include the code that I am using.

Comment: You can't use field editor classes like this outside of a `FieldEditorPreferencePage` because the field editors expect to be able to adjust the page layout and it won't work properly when not in a `FieldEditorPreferencePage`

Comment: That was the issue, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use field editor classes such as `BooleanFieldEditor` like this outside of a `FieldEditorPreferencePage` because the field editors expect to be able to adjust the page layout and it won't work properly when not in a `FieldEditorPreferencePage`.